# Do jQuery CSS files contain security vulnerabilities, or just the JS files?

Tags: jquery, security, xss

Older versions of jQuery contain some vulnerabilities as outlined here: https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-6538/product_id-11031/opxss-1/Jquery-Jquery.html.

The typical remedy is to upgrade jQuery to the latest version. My question is this - jQuery contains both .js and .css files (and same with jQuery-UI). Are the .css files themselves at risk or just the .js files?

I realize that if one is upgrading the JS he should also upgrade the corresponding CSS, but I'm just wondering if the css files themselves contain any risk or if it's just the js files.

Comment: jQuery doesn't contain CSS only jQuery UI does, and only JavaScript code was vulnerable. But note that you should always match the CSS version with the JS version (with any library) otherwise, something may not work properly.